# Is it possible to "undefine" a feature in QT Creator?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, qt-creator, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to modify an application I've completed in QT Creator so that it can be run within a browser. The majority of code in qopenglfunctions_3_2_core.h is skipped because opengles2 is defined in the following line.

```
#if !defined(QT_NO_OPENGL) && !QT_CONFIG(opengles2)
```

```
/*
    The QT_CONFIG macro implements a safe compile time check for features of Qt.
    Features can be in three states:
        0 or undefined: This will lead to a compile error when testing for it
        -1: The feature is not available
        1: The feature is available
*/
#define QT_CONFIG(feature) (1/QT_FEATURE_##feature == 1)
```

With clang, QT_CONFIG(opengles2) returns 0 and the statement evaluates to true. With emscripten, QT_CONFIG(opengles2) returns 1 and the statement evaluates to false which skips the remainder of the file. I'm trying to find a workaround.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Changing
`#include <QOpenGLFunctions_3_2_Core>` to `#include <QOpenGLFunctions_ES2>` resolved the issue for me. However it seems there were some variables that did not carry over such as

- GL_LINE_SMOOTH
- glVertexAttribIPointer
- glPointSize

If anyone knows of a fix to this please let me know. In the meantime, I'll keep digging around.